# Connecting signals to handlers in gtk3.0 using glade and gtk::builder

Tags: c++, gtk3, glade

I'm trying to connect a simple Button "clicked" signal to a signal handler. I have tried different widgets (Switch, ToggleButton) and signals (signal_clicked(), gtk_signal_clicked...), but always get the

```
startup.cxx:32:9: error: ‘class Glib::Object’ has no member named ‘clicked’
```

message. The UI (including the button) was imported from a glade file.
This is what I got:

```
void Startup::startup() {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.geoquiz");
    Gtk::Window* startWindow = nullptr;
    
    auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create();
    builder->add_from_file("StartDialog.glade");
    
    builder->get_widget("StartDialog", startWindow);
    
    auto start = builder->get_object("start");
    start->signal.clicked().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(&Startup::capitalSetHandler));
    
    app->run(*startWindow);
}
```

Obviously I have tried to find the solution in the gnome developer guide to gtk3/gtk4, but it doesn't solve the problem.
First time using Gtk.

Comment: I think the problem is that `start` in your code is not a `Gtk::Button` but rather the base class `Gtk::Object`. Try this instead: `Gtk::Button *start; builder->get_widget("start", start);`

Comment: This seems to have been it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
start
```

was a "Gobject" instead of a "Button" and as such did have any signals.
The declaration

```
Gtk::Button *start;
```

and `get_widget` instead of `gtk_object` solved the problem.
Thanks to G.Sliepen.